# A little dice game that does not echo properly

Tags: php, echo, dice

This is a dice game, when the user chooses a number and hit submit, the page randomly shows a number on the dice and if the user guessed right it should say yes you got it right, otherwise it will say sorry you are wrong. But it would not echo "you guessed right!" when the number matches. Where is the problem? It says sorry it's wrong no matter what. Thank you so much!

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Dice Game!</h1>

<h1>"Please guess a number on the dice!"</h1>


<?php
if ($_POST['subBtn']) {
    $num = $_POST['number'];

    if ($num == "$roll") {
        $comment = "you guessed right!";
    } else if ($num != "$roll") {
        $comment = "sorry it's wrong!";
    } 
}
?>

<p>     
<form name="number" action="activity-dice-game.php" method="post">
<select name="number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"name="subBtn" value="submit"/></input>
</form>
</p>

<?php
$roll = rand(1,6); 
echo "<p>You rolled a " . $roll . ". </p>";
echo "<img src=\"images/die" . $roll . ".gif\" alt=\"die image\">";
?>

</b> <? echo $comment; ?><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you also seem to have a lot of trailing tags, and youve also used php short tags at the end of the file (at some point your world will explode)..

Comment: You should be seeing ERRORS if you bother to look in your PHP error log. You dont work out `$roll` until AFTER you attempt to test it against the selection

Comment: If you run it, you get an undefined variable notice because you are trying to reference a variable (`$roll`) before it's been defined.

Comment: `if ($num == "$roll") {` _Undefined variable $roll_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you load the form `$roll` is set to nothing when you check to see if the `$num` the user submitted is equal to it! That means that no matter what

```
if($num == $roll)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if($num == null)
```

Which will never be true!

Just put `$roll = rand(1,6)` at the top of the script.

Comment: Erm... Where do you see `if($num == $rand)` in the code

Comment: @RiggsFolly my bad! I got rand stuck in my head. Edited

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Dice Game!</h1>

<h1>"Please guess a number on the dice!"</h1>


<?php
if ($_POST['subBtn']) {
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $roll = rand(1,6); 

    if ($num == "$roll") {
        $comment = "you guessed right!";
    } else if ($num != "$roll") {
        $comment = "sorry it's wrong!";
    } 
}
?>

<p>     
<form name="number" action="activity-dice-game.php" method="post">
<select name="number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"name="subBtn" value="submit"/></input>
</form>
</p>

<?php
echo "<p>You rolled a " . $roll . ". </p>";
echo "<img src=\"images/die" . $roll . ".gif\" alt=\"die image\">";
?>

</b> <? echo $comment; ?><br />

</body>
</html>
```